# Is there any built in functions in c++ win 32 for number system conversions?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am doing calculator application.

For the Decimal, Binary, Octal and Hexadecimal numbers. For that I need to convert numbers from one to another number system. So can any one tell me about any built in functions for conversions, eg. Dec to Binary, in c++.

If there is no built in functions, can anyone suggest me a standard code to convert between Dec to Binary, Dec to Octal ,Dec to Hex and Vice a versa.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

`wsprintf` *can* do some limited numeric conversions, but I'd generally advise against using it.

Although they're in the standard library instead of the Win32 API *per se*, I'd use `std::to_string` if your compiler/library are new enough to include it, and `strtol` otherwise.

For converting a number to a string, you can use a stringstream for hex, octal or decimal. For binary, you generally want to create a `std::bitset` from the number first, then write that to the stream.

Comment: Also for converting number to string containing it's represantion with some base winapi `_itoa` function could be used.